# SimpleStorage with Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on an extension for Firefox v.42.0. In it, I have the Addon and on detecting a certain page, the addon injects some code into the page DOM. I am trying to use `var simpleStorage = require("sdk/simple-storage");` to include simpleStorage. I save the variable as follows

```
simpleStorage.storage.token = $value;
```

and then trying to access the simpleStorage in the injected code as follows

```
if (private_self_options === undefined)
    var private_self_options = self.options;

var token = private_self_options.simpleStorage.storage.token;
```

However, this always returns an empty string. Could someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: This addon I saw just yesterday and tried it out in my Firefox Developer Version, but I couldn't see any way to access the "Simple Storage".  I tried it in hopes I could use it to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348230/firefox-addon-sdk-error-unable-to-remvoe-from-inner-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of `simpleStorage.storage.token` into `token` with simply

```
var token = simpleStorage.storage.token
```

`self.options` is for use on the content script side, as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/self#options).  Using it to pass information from simple-storage might be done thus:

```
tab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: "./content-script.js",
  contentScriptOptions: {
    token: simpleStorage.storage.token
  }
});
```

In that case, your assignment statement in `./content-script.js` would be

```
var token = self.options.token;
```