# Firefox addon SDK error: Unable to Remove from Inner-Toolbar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

After hours and hours trying to get things working, I have this error in my console:

```
[CustomizableUI] Widget action-button--myAddonID-misspelutton not found, unable to remove from inner-toolbar-myAddonID-the-title-of-my-addon1 CustomizableUI.jsm:171
```

So, the addon's widget id is misspelled somehow and stuck somewhere.  The term does not appear in any of my code.

Details: I originally built this addon using XUL overlays, and am rebuilding it with the Firefox AddOn SDK.  I think (but I'm not sure) this problem happens like this: I installed my signed addon from the Firefox Addon Repo, and then I used `jpm post --post-url http://localhost:8888/` to install it into Firefox Developer Edition running the [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/autoinstaller/).

In my code I had this, but I've removed it and everything that pertains to it:

```
const { CustomizableUI } = Cu.import('resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm', {});
```

**[update]**

I have also tried this:  uninstall the addon, enter customization mode and choose "Restore to Defaults" which resets all the toolbars to default.  Then I exited Firefox and restarted it.  When I run jpm to install the addon, the error code persists.

Funny thing also is this:  when I view the button using the toolbox inspector, it shows the #id of that button just like in the error.

With that said, how do I resolve the problem without creating a new firefox profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was "jammed" in the profile.

I knew this after I removed all code relating to `customizableUI`, then uninstalling the addon and then using "Restore Defaults" in the customization panel, restarting Firefox and reinstalling the addon, but the problem persisted.

So instead of using this with my existing profile:

```
jpm post --post-url http://localhost:8888/
```

I used this to run it on a fresh clean one:

```
jpm run --binary "C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"
```

*(I was using `post` instead of `run` because I run multiple instances of Firefox and did not want `run` to cause them to exit; but adding `--binary` and the path to Firefox dev did the trick )*

In a fresh profile everything works just fine, even *with* the code utilizing `CustomizableUI`.  There are no errors relating to that in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The 'widget' module has been deprecated due to a number of performance and usability issues, and has been removed from the SDK as of Firefox 40. Please use the 'sdk/ui/button/action' or 'sdk/ui/button/toggle' module
https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui
https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action
https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle

Comment: The reason I am using customizableUI is so I can attach a mouseover event to the control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322949/firefox-addon-sdk-onmouseover-event-for-a-button/34344292#34344292  In my old XUL addon this was easily done.  The SDK provides no way of doing it.

Comment: I remove all of the code that uses the widget and the message remains.  I think it is something stuck in some firefox cache.